# Command errored out with exit status 1: Building wheel for pysph (setup.py) ... error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I have tried to install PySPH to my PC Windows 10. I have done all of what I have to following the Installation and getting started at pysph.com including some of tips for Windows. When I executed 'pip install pysph', it looked almost ok but always errored out 'Building wheel for pysph (setup.py) ... error'.
I am not so much knowledge about setting up the software development environment at all.

Could someone kindly help me to advise me on/resolve this problem, please?

(base) C:\Users\terha>pip install pysph
Collecting pysph
Using cached PySPH-1.0a6.tar.gz (2.7 MB)

Building wheels for collected packages: pysph
Building wheel for pysph (setup.py) ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'C:\Users\terha\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\terha\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0mahwwc_\pysph\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\terha\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0mahwwc_\pysph\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\terha\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-5gc9xj6n'
cwd: C:\Users\terha\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0mahwwc_\pysph
Complete output (493 lines):
C:\Users\terha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Main.py:369: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: C:\Users\terha\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp7g08ussh\check_omp.pyx
tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
check_omp.c
check_omp.obj : warning LNK4197: export 'PyInit_check_omp' specified multiple times; using first specification
Creating library C:\Users\terha\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp7g08ussh\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\Users\terha\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp7g08ussh\check_omp.cp37-win_amd64.lib and object C:\Users\terha\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp7g08ussh\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\Users\terha\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp7g08ussh\check_omp.cp37-win_amd64.exp
Generating code
Finished generating code

Comment: I am having the same problem and could not solve it. I guess people downvoting this question don´t know anything about PySPH and well actually they don´t have to. This must be an issue of the PySPH package which came out after some of the dependences were updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just install it using pip you need to follow the steps in [documentation](https://pysph.readthedocs.io/en/1.0a1/installation.html#installing-the-dependencies-on-windows) first.